# Kafka broker unable to recover

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am running a 5 node kafka broker with a 5 node zookeeper ensemble.

On Kafka nodes I keep getting this error

```
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,345] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.105.23.188/10.105.23.188:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,345] INFO Socket connection established to 10.105.23.188/10.105.23.188:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,346] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x55861d8ea6f0000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,721] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.105.25.4/10.105.25.4:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,721] INFO Socket connection established to 10.105.25.4/10.105.25.4:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,722] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x55861d8ea6f0000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,841] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.105.24.4/10.105.24.4:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:11,841] WARN Session 0x55861d8ea6f0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
[2016-11-14 19:05:12,319] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.105.27.23/10.105.27.23:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:12,319] INFO Socket connection established to 10.105.27.23/10.105.27.23:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:12,320] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x55861d8ea6f0000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-11-14 19:05:12,395] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-5], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@3fbe518f. Possible cause: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'responses': Error reading array of size 1204063, only 920 bytes available (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

On Zookeeper nodes :
I get the following on the leader

```
2016-11-14 19:14:47,502 [myid:4] - ERROR [LearnerHandler-/10.105.25.4:50099:LearnerHandler@631] - Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:83)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler.run(LearnerHandler.java:513)
```

When a consumer tries to read from this cluster it get this error repeatedly

```
2016-11-14 19:17:36,847 WARN {main} [kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:handleResponse:629] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1603 : {=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Please help me debug this. The consumers have auto commit enabled. If you need me to provide more configuration please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you enable any security for Kafka? If not, check whether you are consuming a non-existent topic.

Comment: When I list the topics on the kafka cluster I do see the topic that I am writing to.
Also I have no security enabled for Kafka.

Comment: How did you specify the topic to be consumed? By KafkaConsumer.subscribe or manual assigment?

Comment: KafkaConsumer.subscribe() .